# Mq4 sensor doesnt detect natural gas but detects cigarette lighter gas only!

Tags: arduino, sensor, smoke-sensor, gas-sensor

I am working on a project for detecting natural gas of cooking stoves, I have tested several sensors but the mq4 sensor was the one that worked fine.

Now after about one month of using the sensor i bought, it is no more detecting natural gas from the stove and only detects the cigarette lighter gas!

I have two and they both showed the same problem after more than month period.
I have tried changing the potentiometer several times after this error occurred,unfortunately they didn't respond.

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The detector has its manufacturer. They are the right address for your question.

Answer (score 10):

From what you're describing, it sounds as if the sensor has been damaged. [The datasheet for this part](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/MQ-4%20Ver1.3%20-%20Manual.pdf) gives warnings about a number of different conditions that can cause damage. You mention having tested the sensor with a cigarette lighter, and this seems like the most likely cause of your problem:

> 2.2 Used in high gas concentration
>
> No matter the sensor is electrified or not, if it is placed in high gas concentration for long time, sensors characteristic will be affected. **If lighter gas sprays the sensor, it will cause extremely damage.**

Replace the sensor, and stop using a cigarette lighter for testing.